# how to add column in datatable dynamically using size of object

Tags: hibernate, jsf, jpa

In my project I have a `Country` class and `Language` class and they have `one-to-many` relationship. I have to display all languages on the basis of logged in user. The logged in user has a specific country. Using session:

1. I have to put logged in user in sessin
2. Get associated country using session.

I have written queries for retrieving `Country` for the logged-in user but I don't know how to put the object in session and how to get it.

```
public UsersDetails getUserById(String loggedInUserEid) {

    UsersDetails user = null;
    try{

    user = entityManager.find(UsersDetails.class, loggedInUserEid);
    if(user!=null){
        System.out.println("userList.get(0).getFirstName()::"+user.getFirstName());
    }
    }catch(EntityNotFoundException enfEx){
        System.out.println("LoggedIn User not found in DB");
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("UserDAOImpl.getUserById()::Exit");
    return (null!=user) ? user : null;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing I'm not sure which layer does the code above resides, is this a JSF managed bean or what?

If it is a JSF managed bean you can create a User Class to store the information your want, but if you just want to save **UserDetails** object in the session you can do that by using FacesContext like so

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("userInfo", getUserById("someId"));
```

And you can retrieve the session info by

```
(UsersDetails)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("userInfo");
```